# Reversão de revisão

Tags: debate

Como lidar quando se faz uma edição que visa melhorar uma pergunta e o autor da pergunta, normalmente usuário novo, vai lá e reverte ou rejeita?

Vejam essa publicação: [Tela de Menu tkinter](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/358693/tela-de-menu-tkinter).

Código postado sem estar formatado corretamente, corrigi, e o autor da pergunta rejeitou a revisão.

Comment: Complicado, deixar um comentário informando sobre a edição e recomendando a leitura do **tour**, entre outro é importante.

Comment: @NoobSaibot é, pode ser uma saída, porque não tem muito o que fazer nessas situações. Eu refiz a edição, daqui a pouco o usuário vai lá e reverte de novo. Observemos.

Comment: Apesar **Cadu**, que não há no [histórico de revisões](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/posts/358693/revisions), rejeição ou reversão de edição, há apenas que o AP removeu e restaurou a questão, pode ser que por ele ter removido automaticamente rejeitou (não sei se isso é possível).

Comment: Eu sou novato aqui e queria entender o espirito da coisa(filosofia da comunidade). Fazer o código da tela e os botões da maneira que o usuário solicitou é fácil. O problema é que uma pessoa que tenha escrito aqueles três formulários certamente faria mais um formulário com três botões. Esse não é o tipo de pergunta que deveria ser encerrada já que é evidente que o usuário procura alguém para terminar algo que ele começou sem efetuar esforço.

Comment: @Augusto é, no fundo eu acho que deveria ser fechada sim. Ele não deixou claro o problema dele, só jogou um monte de código lá. Dificilmente alguém vai conseguir sequer reproduzir o problema dele.

Comment: @Cadu,eu revise o código dele e não encontrei nenhum problema. Ele só quer alguém  para escrever um formulário principal que chame modalmente aqueles formulários que ele jogou na questão.

Comment: @NoobSaibot Se não me engano, edições sugeridas que são rejeitadas não aparecem no histórico de revisões.

Comment: @hkotsubo também passou por minha mente, mais não sei.

Comment: @AugustoVasques A pergunta não foi fechada e não possui nenhum voto de fechamento até então. De qq forma, não é o foco da discussão. O que o Cadu quer saber é o que fazer quando uma edição sugerida é rejeitada pelo autor da pergunta. Isso faz parte do "espírito da coisa": perguntas focadas e sem misturar assuntos (isso vale tanto para o site principal quanto para o meta). **Se** a pergunta for fechada e vc discordar, aí vc pode [abrir outra discussão](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) a respeito. Já aqui, vamos manter o foco no que foi perguntado (sobre a edição rejeitada).

Comment: Aliás, @Cadu, acho que não tem muito o que fazer a não ser deixar um comentário questionando e explicando, com links para a central de ajuda, etc. Eu sugiro colocar [este link](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/editing), por exemplo, já que o fato de qualquer poder editar qualquer coisa é um dos aspectos do site que vários usuários acham "estranho" no começo, e acho válido explicar que isso é normal e benéfico.

Comment: @hkotsubo vou guardar esse link pro próximo caso.